# DHTMLX. How to query from a database for list Units?

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

now, i get list Units from Database:

```
    var sections = scheduler.serverList("type");
          scheduler.createUnitsView({
             name:"unit",
             property:"type",
             list:sections
          }); 
       $list = new OptionsConnector($res, $dbtype);
$list->render_table("doctors","id","id(value),first_name(first_name),last_name(last_name),middle_name(middle_name),spec(spec),image(image)");
$scheduler = new schedulerConnector($res, $dbtype);
$scheduler->set_options("type", $list);
```

But i want some query from Database for this. No render all values from Databases, just result from "Select *******"
Is it possible? Render_sql? Thank you advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use **render_sql** method for this:

```
$list = new OptionsConnector($res, $dbtype);
$list->render_sql(
   "SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE someColumn > " .$list->sql->escape("someValue") . " AND anotherColumn < ". $list->sql->escape("anotherValue"),
   "id",
   "id(value),first_name(first_name),last_name(last_name),middle_name(middle_name),spec(spec),image(image)"
);

$scheduler = new schedulerConnector($res, $dbtype);
$scheduler->set_options("type", $list);
```

The first parameter takes the sql query, and the rest parameters are the same as in **render_table**.
Also note that connectors don't support parameterized queries, but you can use $connector->sql->escape method if you need to insert request values into the query